# Prompt user with email when Disk Usage is over 200GB

Tags: shell, scripting, find, disk

```
find . -printf "%u  %s\n" | awk '{user[$1]+=$2}; END{ for( i in user) print i " " user[i]}'
```

Hi I have been using the above CMDline to look for each user's disk usage information. I would like to know whether is there a method to send the users an email if they exceed 200gb on the disks with an automated script? Thanks

Note: There are 10 users in the disks

Comment: Do you have quotas enabled?

Comment: Hi, nope unfortunately I dont and i am not able to.

Comment: On my system (4 users, 2 wihh little/nothing in ~/, one with a few gigs, and one with 250+gb) `sudo du -sh *` runs MUCH quicker than the find/awk combo does for me.  parse that for a string that matches 19[0-9]GB and then cut off the user part, use that as input to a `mail` call (even though you don't have quotas enabled you can check the quotad cron that sends reminders)

Comment: Hi, due to restriction purposes, I am not able to run as an administrator, So that's why i ran the find/awk cmdline